# Different coloured navigation links in Twenty Eleven themes

Tags: navigation, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm [working on a website](http://sundialcoaching.com/) for a friend with small changes. She's running Twenty Eleven theme an she wants to make each link's bottom border (that I'll be putting in soon) a different colour. However with the CSS I'll be putting in, I only know how to make all of them a singular colour like this - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85495001/nav.jpg

Is there a plugin or some extra code I can put into the navigation code of this theme to allow for this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom html classes to each menu item and then use those classes to add the bottom border.

In the Admin Dashboard, under Appearance, click on Menus.

Select your menu and click the small down arrow to the right of the menu item box.

If the CSS Classes box is missing, Click the Screen Options tab at the top of the page and check the `CSS Classes` option.

In the CSS Classes box add the class for the color of the bottom border you want to used. For example `nav-yellow`, `nav-green`, etc.

In your style sheet, add the corresponding class styles:

```
.nav-yellow {
}

.nav-green {
}
```

Comment: Okay. I remember seeing that step but I never saw the classes so I was thinking it didn't come with the theme. But your scree options extra step helped! Thanks!